# NFS_AutoMount not mounting readynas shares Ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: server, automount, nfs

Hi all got `NFS_automount` installed on a server running Ubuntu 14.04.
The problem is that automoun` won't mount the NFS share I have on my readynas.

This is from the conf file:

```
MOUNTOPTS="hard,intr,tcp,actimeo=3"
MOUNTS=( "rw|readynas|/c/media/TV/|/mnt/tv/|nfs_automount_rw_testfile" )
```

This is the log:

```
nfs_automount [2014-08-01 19:53:51+01:00]: [NOTE] Monitoring started.
nfs_automount [2014-08-01 19:53:51+01:00]: [INFO] (dataset 1) Remote server/NFS service at 'readynas' available.
nfs_automount [2014-08-01 19:53:51+01:00]: [CRIT] (dataset 1) Remote NFS share 'readynas:/c/media/TV/' is unmounted; attempting mount.
nfs_automount [2014-08-01 19:53:51+01:00]: [CRIT] Remote share '/c/media/TV/' unavailable!
nfs_automount [2014-08-01 19:53:51+01:00]: [INFO] Sleeping for 60 seconds.
```

I can mount the share manually with:

```
sudo mount -t nfs readynas:/media/TV /mnt/tv
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your successful manually mount your `MOUNTS` option must be:

> MOUNTS=( "rw|readynas|/media/TV/|/mnt/tv/|nfs_automount_rw_testfile" )

(without `/c` at the beginning)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This may answer the question, but you could improve the answer by explaining the reason for the change.